# Documents downloading and not opening in browser

Tags: php

I am trying to open my documents in the browser and it keeps downloading the documents.

I have tried different attachment types to replace the force-download to octet-stream and still does the same.

The script also downloads multiple file types from multiple directories based on user ID.

This is what I have got so far;

```
<?php

function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
{
if(!is_readable($file)) die('Error');

$size = filesize($file);
$name = rawurldecode($name);
$known_mime_types=array(
"pdf" => "application/pdf",
"txt" => "text/plain",
"html" => "text/html",
"htm" => "text/html",
"exe" => "application/octet-stream",
"zip" => "application/zip",
"doc" => "application/msword",
"xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
"ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
"gif" => "image/gif",
"png" => "image/png",
"jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
"wmv" => "application/octet-stream",
"jpg" => "image/jpg",
"php" => "text/plain"
);
if($mime_type==''){
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
$mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
} else {
$mime_type="application/force-download";
};
};

@ob_end_clean();


if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
$range=intval($range);
if(!$range_end) {
$range_end=$size-1;
} else {
$range_end=intval($range_end);
}
$new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
header("Content-Length: $new_length");
header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
} else {
$new_length=$size;
header("Content-Length: ".$size);
}
$chunksize = 1*(1024*1024);
$bytes_send = 0;
if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
{
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
fseek($file, $range);

while(!feof($file) &&
(!connection_aborted()) &&
($bytes_send<$new_length)
)
{
$buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
print($buffer);
flush();
$bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
}
fclose($file);
} else

die('Error - can not open file.');
die();
}
set_time_limit(0);
$file_path='uploads/'.$_REQUEST['uid']."upd"."/".$_REQUEST['filename'];
output_file($file_path, ''.$_REQUEST['filename'].'', 'text/plain');
?>
```

Solution for opening file in browser;

```
<?php
    $file_path='uploads/'.$_REQUEST['uid']."upd"."/".$_REQUEST['filename'];
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile($file_path);
?>
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: Documents will just download unless the MIME type is something the browser will accept. Some browsers are really fussy. `octet-stream` is the type you use when you *want* it to download.

Comment: If the browser doesn't have the appropriate app for a particular document, it will pop up the option for download, say for example, excel or powerpoint documents .

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#syntax - Perhaps you can use the `Content-Disposition: inline` response header to force the browser to display instead of download (`attachment`)?

Comment: I will give that a go, thanks :)

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: No, my issue has not been solved :(

Comment: I have resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $file_path='uploads/'.$_REQUEST['uid']."upd"."/".$_REQUEST['filename'];
    header("Content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile($file_path);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.